# How do I say "whatever" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How do I say "whatever" in German? I am going to use it in this context:

> A: "Lass uns morgen ins Kino gehen!"
>        (Let's go to the movies tomorrow!)
>
> B: "Nein. Ich muß mich noch auf meine Prüfung vorbereiten."
>        (No. I still need to prepare for the test.)
>
> A: "Wie auch immer!"
>        (Whatever!)

Is "Wie auch immer" a proper translation for "whatever"?

Comment: In dem Fall ist es "Wie du meinst."

Comment: "Meinetwegen." expresses lukewarm assent - possibly still a bit less lukewarm than in English.

Comment: "Whatever" has a strong implication of a disinterested teenager. "Clean up your room". "Whatever". Getting that across seems difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Was auch immer!

is also in common usage.

Comment: I don't think "Was auch immer" fits in this context

Answer (score 8):

There are a few option that would work in this context

> Sei's drum.
>
> (Ach) und selbst wenn.
>
> (Ach) und wenn schon.
>
> (Ach) was soll's.

The "Ach" is a discarding one in this case.
Besides those you could also say

> Na und?

but that would be a question. The message is the same though. And to give you something to use with your buddies (and only with them)

> (Ach) scheiß (doch) drauf.
>
> Drauf geschissen!

*Wie auch immer* doesn't fit IMO but that might just be personal preference.
All those work for this context but they will not work for other contexts of *anyway*.

Comment: Bei uns sagt man auch noch "Egal", das könnte aber regional sein.

Answer (score 2):

It depends!

Do you mean "Whatever, fine, let's not go then?" In that case, *Wie du meinst* is good. (It sounds a little snippy to me, like "Have it your way" in English, but I'm not sure about that.) *Na gut* would be fine too, especially in *Na gut, Samstag denn?*

But if you mean, "Whatever, just blow off your homework" (which is what it sounds like to me), then you want *Egal*, as in *Ist doch egal!*

Answer (score -4):

"Wie auch immer" is *howsoever* in German. "Was auch immer" is *whatever* in German.

Comment: Even though probably correct, this does not seem to answer the question.